# ParseError syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) (0)

Tags: php, битрикс

Выходит ошибка [ParseError]  syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH) (0), но немогу понять где тут ошибка, вроде все правильно

```
<?foreach($arElement["PRICES"] as $code=>$arPrice):?>
<?
$arGroupAvalaible = array(8,9); // массив групп, которые в которых нужно проверить доступность пользователя
$arGroups = CUser::GetUserGroup($USER->GetID()); // массив групп, в которых состоит пользователь
$result_intersect = array_intersect($arGroupAvalaible, $arGroups);// далее проверяем, если пользователь вошёл хотя бы в одну из групп
if(!empty($result_intersect)){
?>
<?
if ($arPrice["PRICE_ID"] == "6") //Показываем ему тип цены с ID-6 (и только ее)
{
echo $arPrice["VALUE"].' руб.';
}
?>
<?}else{?> //Если не вошел ни в одну из перечисленных
<?
if($arPrice["PRICE_ID"] == "3") { //Показываем цену с ID-3 (в моем случае розничная)
{
echo $arPrice["VALUE"].' руб.';
}
?>
<?}?>
<?endforeach;?>⁠
```

Comment: Я не вижу здесь кусков html-кода, если так, то зачем вам понадобилось каждый раз закрывать и открывать `<? ... ?>`? Перепишите код начисто и сможете увидеть, что в одном из условий if есть лишняя открывающая фигурная скобка. Если бы писали код начисто, не допустили бы этой ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

```
<? foreach ($arElement["PRICES"] as $code => $arPrice) {

    $arGroupAvalaible = [8, 9]; // массив групп, которые в которых нужно проверить доступность пользователя
    $arGroups = CUser::GetUserGroup($USER->GetID()); // массив групп, в которых состоит пользователь
    $result_intersect = array_intersect($arGroupAvalaible, $arGroups);// далее проверяем, если пользователь вошёл хотя бы в одну из групп

    if (!empty($result_intersect)) {
        if ($arPrice["PRICE_ID"] == "6") //Показываем ему тип цены с ID-6 (и только ее)
        {
            echo $arPrice["VALUE"] . ' руб.';
        }
    } else {
        if ($arPrice["PRICE_ID"] == "3") { //Показываем цену с ID-3 (в моем случае розничная)
            echo $arPrice["VALUE"] . ' руб.';
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?foreach($arElement["PRICES"] as $code=>$arPrice):?>
    <?
    $arGroupAvalaible = array(8,9); // массив групп, которые в которых нужно проверить доступность пользователя
    $arGroups = CUser::GetUserGroup($USER->GetID()); // массив групп, в которых состоит пользователь
    $result_intersect = array_intersect($arGroupAvalaible, $arGroups);// далее проверяем, если пользователь вошёл хотя бы в одну из групп
    if(!empty($result_intersect)){
    ?>
    <?
    if ($arPrice["PRICE_ID"] == "6") //Показываем ему тип цены с ID-6 (и только ее)
    {
    echo $arPrice["VALUE"].' руб.';
    }
    ?>

<?}else{?> //Если не вошел ни в одну из перечисленных
<?
if($arPrice["PRICE_ID"] == "3") **{ была лишняя**
{
echo $arPrice["VALUE"].' руб.';
}
?>
<?}?>
<?endforeach;?>
```